# Stretching a 2D Array in Java

Tags: arrays, 2d

I need to "Stretch" a 2D array in java.. That is, replicate each column the given number of times.

Example:

```
***
**
*
```

would turn to (Assuming N = 2)

```
******
****
**
```

I cant for the life of me figure out how to write down what im thinking...

Heres what I have started

```
public void stretch ( int factor )
{


for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < pixels[0].length; col++){
            if (pixels[row][col] == '*'){

                pixels[row][col] = '*' * factor;

                }


        }       
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are actually asking because when you display in your figure and what you want seem a bit different.

```
***
**
*

factor = 2;

******
****
**
```

I just did the solution to figure out the graph correctly. This might help.

```
public static void stretch ( int factor )
{

    int[][] pixels = new int[5][5];
    int length = pixels.length;
    while(length > 0){
        for(int i = length*factor; i > 0; i--){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        length--;
    }
}
```